# Apply kaleo Workflow for document and library in liferay

Tags: workflow, liferay-6

I am use Liferay 6.2.
I would apply kaleo workflow for document portlet !
Can you help me?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in using kaleo workflow between Web Contents or Documents and Media. Just make sure you use context variables available for given type (this might be usefull for you https://www.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-kaleo-workflow-context-variables) The one thing which might be not so obvious, is the place where you configure Documents and Media workflow.

If you want to define workflow for Documents and Media:

1. Go to documents media section
2. Click edit on main folder (or different one which you want workflow to be applied)[image: Edit on documents and media folder]
3. Select workflow from select[image: Select workflow]

Comment: @ĐỗViếtNgà No problem. Do you mind mark it, if solution helped you? ;-) Thanks in advice.